# Does Java in Android compiles to machine code?

Tags: java, android

Based on my understanding, Java compiles to bytecode, but when compiling a Java program for Android, does Java compile to bytecode or to machine code?

Comment: Java always compiles to bytecode, but this bytecode  is then interpreted by a JVM (Java virtual machine) that is implemented to work specifically on the target platform. For example, if in java you ask to read a file, the bytecode will always be the same instruction to read a file. However, the target JVM which runs this instruction will adapt the actual operation of reading the file differently if it runs on Windows rather than if it runs on Linux or any other OS such as Android.

Comment: That's why you can write java source code, compile it into a jar and run that jar anywhere. It will be the specific JVM (made differently for each platform) handling the adaptation of those operations to the target OS, unlike other languages such as C++ for which the compiled .exe will be specific to the platform it is compiled on and can't be used into a different platform.

Answer (score 2):

Android does use bytecode, but it doesn't use JVM bytecode, or jars.  It uses the [dex format](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik).  The Android device may do some amount of AOT and JIT compilation, as discussed [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/configure).